# passing a variable inside a variable to an angular directive in html

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-material

I am doing a signup form with a few steps, made with angular material tabs. I have 5 tabs each containing a few inputs that the user should fill in. I also have 2 buttons below the tabs, one to get to the next tab and one button to get to the previous tab. I want to disable the upcoming tabs and also disable the button that takes the user to the next tab until the user has filled in the the tab he is on properly. I want the user to be able to go back and change the information that is already filled in on the previous tabs, and when all the tabs are filled in properly a send button is shown. So, that's basic functions for a multi step signup form.

I have managed to do the basic functions for the buttons and the tabs with `ng-disabled` and `ng-hide` combined with changing the value on the variable `tabNr` in my controller, like hiding the previous-button on the first tab and hiding the next-button on the last tab, and that works fine.

When it comes to hide the next-button based on if the form is filled in its a bit more tricky. I am able to disable the next tab by validating the form on the previous tab like this: `ng-disabled="!tab1Form.$valid"`, so that's hard coded and works fine.

The previous- and next-buttons, though, are the same for all tabs and that is the tricky part, so I can't just disable the button if a form isn't valid because the button does not know which tab that is active. I have tried to make a function in the controller but then the problem is that the valid-variable is just a thing in html and I cant evaluate it in the controller.. As far as I have tried and have understood.

So this is the next-button:

```
<md-button ng-click="FormCtrl.tabNext()" ng-disabled="FormCtrl.tabNr >= 5 || !tab{{FormCtrl.tabNr}}Form.$valid" ng-hide="FormCtrl.tabNr > 4">Next</md-button>
```

Each tab has this, with it's own number:

```
<form name="tab1Form" novalidate>
```

What I've tried is to change the tab, that should trigger the disable, by using angular:

```
ng-disabled="!tab{{FormCtrl.tabNr}}Form.$valid"
```

The browser seems to change the number, and it works for the first tab, but on the rest of the tabs it does not disable the button even though it should, like if the browser does not evaluate the variable properly. I hoped that it should work because I cant think of another way of doing it with these variables...

Does this way of using angular simply not work or am I doing anything wrong? Does anyone have a solution I could use?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller

```
function Controller($scope){
   var vm = this;

   vm.form = $scope['tab' + anyNumber + 'Form'];

}
```

then in your html

```
ng-disabled="!FormCtrl.form.$valid"
```

Comment: Your solution is not working. Using scope does not work. If i remove scope, the variable `FormCtrl.form` is working, but `!FormCtrl.form.$valid` is not getting evaluated properly.